# node js Oauth2 token management

Tags: oauth-2.0, ip, limit, access-token, lifecycle

I develop expressjs app with Oauth2 authorization. For a while I used my own library for token management, but I realized that it has a lot of the vices I want to fix. Search in npmjs.org gave me the token-manager package, but I don't see the functional I expected to see. I would like to have something like this:

- Limitation of tokens number for the same user on a single IP.
- Refresh token limit.
- Tokens per second limit for the same user.

Ideally I would like to use well tested package that solves common problems of token management, since I am not aware of all ones.
What is the common practice?

P.S. I have not found any common practice and published my own npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth2-token-manager